# maximum recursion depth exceeded in python multiple dialog

Tags: python, pyqt4, multi-window

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window_Test3(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        global progress_flag
        **self.Next_Window = Window_Test1()   # Return Window_Test1() but RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded**

  self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800,480)
        self.setWindowTitle('TEST PROCESSING')

        quit = QtGui.QPushButton('Close', self)

        quit.setGeometry(10, 10, 60, 35)

        test = QtGui.QPushButton('TEST 3', self)
        test.setGeometry(100, 200, 200, 100)


        self.connect(quit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.reject)
        self.connect(test, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.nextWindow)

    def nextWindow(self):

        self.Next_Window.show()

class Window_Test2(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        global progress_flag
        self.Window3 = Window_Test3()

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint|QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 480)
        self.setWindowTitle('TEST PROCESSING')

        self.quit = QtGui.QPushButton('Close', self)
        self.quit.setGeometry(10, 10, 60, 35)

        test = QtGui.QPushButton('TEST 2', self)
        test.setGeometry(250, 220, 200, 100)

        self.connect(self.quit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.reject)

        self.connect(test, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.nextWindow)

    def nextWindow(self):

        self.Window3.show()

class Window_Test1(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.Window2 = Window_Test2()

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 480)
        self.setWindowTitle('TEST PROCESSING' )

        test = QtGui.QPushButton('TEST', self)
        test.setGeometry(100,100,100,100)

        quit = QtGui.QPushButton('Close', self)
        quit.setGeometry(10, 10, 60, 35)

        self.connect(test, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.nextWindow)

        self.connect(quit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.reject)

    def nextWindow(self):
        self.Window2.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window1 = Window_Test1()
    Window1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I formatted your code so that it renders properly (indent all code lines by four spaces to do that). However, it is very unclear to me what the problem with this code is. Can you add any errors you see, a description of what you expect to happen and what actually happens? You can use the edit button under your question to add this information.

Comment: lass Window_Test3(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        global progress_flag
  => Error     **self.Next_Window = Window_Test1()                                 The error contents are as follows.=>                                                             # Return Window_Test1() but RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a placeholder `self.next_Window` for the next window and fill it in after creating all 3 windows

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window_Test3(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        global progress_flag
        self.next_Window = None

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint|
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint|
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800,480)
        self.setWindowTitle('TEST PROCESSING')

        quit = QtGui.QPushButton('Close', self)

        quit.setGeometry(10, 10, 60, 35)

        test = QtGui.QPushButton('TEST 3', self)
        test.setGeometry(100, 200, 200, 100)


        self.connect(quit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.reject)
        self.connect(test, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.nextWindow)

    def nextWindow(self):
        self.next_Window.show()
    def setNextWindow(self, nextWindow):
        self.next_Window = nextWindow

class Window_Test2(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        global progress_flag
        self.next_Window = None

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint|
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint|
                            QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 480)
        self.setWindowTitle('TEST PROCESSING')

        self.quit = QtGui.QPushButton('Close', self)
        self.quit.setGeometry(10, 10, 60, 35)

        test = QtGui.QPushButton('TEST 2', self)
        test.setGeometry(250, 220, 200, 100)

        self.connect(self.quit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.reject)

        self.connect(test, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.nextWindow)

    def nextWindow(self):
        self.next_Window.show()
    def setNextWindow(self, nextWindow):
        self.next_Window = nextWindow

class Window_Test1(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.next_Window = None

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 480)
        self.setWindowTitle('TEST PROCESSING' )

        test = QtGui.QPushButton('TEST', self)
        test.setGeometry(100,100,100,100)

        quit = QtGui.QPushButton('Close', self)
        quit.setGeometry(10, 10, 60, 35)

        self.connect(test, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.nextWindow)
        self.connect(quit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.reject)

    def nextWindow(self):
        self.next_Window.show()
    def setNextWindow(self, nextWindow):
        self.next_Window = nextWindow

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window1 = Window_Test1()
    Window2 = Window_Test2()
    Window3 = Window_Test3()
    Window1.setNextWindow(Window2)
    Window2.setNextWindow(Window3)
    Window3.setNextWindow(Window1)
    Window1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code recursively initializes new objects.

Window_Test1 calls Window_Test2, which calls Window_Test3, which calls Window_Test1, which  calls Window_Test2, which calls Window_Test3, which calls Window_Test1, which... you get the point.

You'll want to either defer the initialization of those objects to when they're actually needed (so not in `__init__`), or maybe have single instances of all three windows that are referred to.

Comment: What if you make them into an inner class where they will be able to have access each other’s info, but I agree, delay the creation in __init__ then

Comment: There should be only one window instead of three.

def nextWindow (self):
         self.next_Window.show ()
         self.actionEvent (self.reject ()) # Delete current screen
     def setNextWindow (self, nextWindow):
         self.next_Window = nextWindow

That is, you add self.actionEvent (self.reject ()),
One screen is output.

However, there is a slight jitter when switching the screen.

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one window instead of three.

```
def nextWindow (self):
    self.next_Window.show()
    self.actionEvent (self.reject ()) # Delete current screen

def setNextWindow (self, nextWindow):
    self.next_Window = nextWindow
```

That is, you add `self.actionEvent(self.reject ())`,

One screen is output.

However, there is a slight jitter when switching the screen.